# Checking all records that return back from database to see if certain records meet criteria. If not, then filter these records out

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter

Stay with me in the explanation. I apologise for the logic needed here but this is what is needed.

I will return all 'events' from the EVENT table, from a simple database query. However from this I would like to then check all records, and see if they fall into certain criteria.

```
event_id |   status       |     last_modified
1        |  pending       |     "2018-09-07"
2        |  approved      |     "2018-09-07"
3        |  cancelled     |     "2018-06-02"
4        |  approved      |     "2018-09-02"
5        |  cancelled     |     "2018-10-08"
```

This is just basic data that would be returned. However, given the data above I want to return all data, but if the event is 'cancelled' AND NOT falling within 36 hours before today [for this example todays timestamp would be 2018/10/08] then this would be excluded from the total list of records returned by the query.

In the list of returned records above, event #3 would not return given its last modification has not been within 36 hours of current/todays timestamp.

This is a very awkward solution, I apologise. I don't want to filter in the where clause as this will not return all other records needed.

Thanks in advance for any advice you have.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't add it to the where clause .

Comment: explain better .. your question   .. your part about the use (or not ) of the where is not clear  .

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 36 hours before today? Your `last_modified` column doesn't contain a time, so you can only compare with "days", i.e. multiples of 24 hours (e.g. 24 hours, 48 hours). Your data won't let you distinguish between "36 hours ago" and "32 hours ago"

Comment: The problem with the missing time aside, this sounds as if you want: `where not ( status = 'cancelled' and last_modified < current_timestamp - interval '36' hour)`

Comment: as other has said. If filtering on the where clause doesnt give you the right result you problem is the where condition. Just show us your Query, Current and Expected result so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select e.*
from events e
where e.status <> 'cancelled' or e.last_modified > current_timestamp - interval '36 hour';
```